# Apache Airflow Ldap Authentication Via Secure Method

Tags: ldap, airflow

We using apacheairflow
but we want use ldap authentication
as I saw config file want AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "**********"  we can not write password like this.
because this method unsecure.
how to hide ldap bind password on this line , we dont any idea for this maybe somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach generally goes via pipeline or a bash script and what we do is

1. we export the password as a variable,
2. template that and generate the values file,
3. install using helm,
4. remove the values.yaml file

You can export your password in a script from a file like
`export LDAP_PASSWORD=$(cat ./ldappassword)`

Now you can write the webserver_config in `values.yaml.j2` as

```
   webserver:
     webserverConfig: |
     #... the other values
     AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "{{ LDAP_PASSWORD }}"
```

**Please Note. This requires `j2cli` to be installed and the extension of values.yaml file is `.j2`**

Now you can replace these templates by calling

`j2 ./values.yaml.j2 > ./values.yaml`

This command replaces templates under `**{{ variables }}**` by the respective env variables.

After this command you can install airflow by
`helm upgrade --install $RELEASE_NAME apache/airflow -n $NAMESPACE -f values.yaml`
and then remove the templated `values.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way.
Create a Kubernetes Secret For the Password

1. `kubectl create secret generic ldap-secret --from-file=ldap-password="ldappassword" -n  $NAMESPACE`
2. Mount the kubernetes secret in webserver via `values.yaml`

```
webserver:
  extraVolumes: 
    - name: ldap
      secret:
        secretName: ldap-secret
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: ldap
      mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/ldappassword
      readOnly: true
```

3. Refer to this volume in `webserver_config` in the `values.yaml` as well.

```
webserver:
  webserverConfig: |
    # ... your other ldap values
    
    with open('/usr/local/airflow/ldappassword/ldap-password','r') as fp:
      x = fp.read()

    AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = x
```